# Consistent Seg Fault from assigning a 2d heap array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I am creating a 2D array like this

```
int** B = calloc(16, sizeof(int*));

for(int i = 0; i <= 16; i++){

B[i] = calloc(16, sizeof(int));

}
```

then i am passing B to a function which calls for a Parameter int**. This function then calls another function which calls for an int** so B is once again passed.

I am able to do this `B[1][1]++;`

but when I try to

```
B[1][0] = 1;
```

I get a segmentation fault.

I have tried so many things and nothing has made it go away.

Edit: Solved!

Ended up being my passing the array B to a function using &B instead of just B that caused the issue, though I implemented the changes suggested below before fixing this error, so possible that I would have run into this out of bounds problem next.

Comment: `i <= 16;` looks out of bounds to me.

Comment: A list of pointers to allocated arrays is not a 2D array.

Comment: @ggorlen to me, too: [16] is OOB.

Comment: Could you tell which C are you complining (flags, version..) ?

Comment: i < 16 not <= to avoid OOB

Comment: @ggorlen could you explain how I would fix this? Because I don't see how I could be out of bounds of I'm trying to change the value of B[1][0] seeing as that would be the first value in the "1" array

Comment: The code `calloc`s memory for 16 `int *` pointers. Their indexes are 0, 1...14, 15 (that's 16 elements in total). So loops should run `0 < length`. But `0 <= length` is 17 elements and when `i == length`, that's one past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior and typically results in a crash. The fix is to use `<` instead of `<=`. If you're confused that the crash is happening at `B[1][0] = 1;`, the reason is that a crash due to undefined behavior might not occur right away. UB means literally anything is possible (including the program appearing to work correctly).

Comment: @ggorlen thank you so much for explaining that makes sense. I'll try to implement the changes

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, you have the condition as `i <= 16` and you have only allocated 16 * size of int*. Hence, you're going out of bounds of your allocated space.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still confused though. How am I out of bounds when assigning B[1][0] shouldnt those be some of the first arrays I initialize or calloc

Comment: You're out of bounds on `B[i] = calloc(16, sizeof(int));` where `i == 16`. See my explanation in the comments above. Arrays are 0-indexed. The crash might happen immediately, at `B[1][0] = 1;` or it might not happen at all (such is the nature of UB). So you can't look at the crash point and assume that's exactly the problem. Use a memory checker like valgrind or asan for debugging these problems. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Yeah. valgrind would you give more information on why it's crashing.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your help so far. Unfortunately I changed the <= to a < as well as made the pointer array larger by one, with the same fault still occuring

Comment: OK, no problem. Can you edit your question to show the exact code you're using as a [mcve]? This way, I can run it and see the problem.

Comment: Yes. Also, more details regarding which compiler you're using? Because I seem to have no issues running a similar program on my system.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen. The problem was actually that at the beginning of my program I passed &B to the function which messed up everything down the line. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem--I guess that's why posting all of the code as a [mcve] is a great idea! You might not know exactly where it all went wrong.